# Increasing speed of Sum of Pairs- Codewars

Tags: python, performance, sum

I've just started learning to code around 2 weeks ago and have come across the below problem. I originally wrote the code as a double nested loop but that unsurprisingly timed out. I have recompiled my code in order to (I think) have an asymptotic run time of O(n) as opposed to O(n^2). I'm looking for ways to make my code faster:

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    minn = min(ints)
    if s < 0:
        minn +- s
    if minn > 0:
        minn = 0
    maxx = max(ints)
    if s > maxx:
        maxx = s
    ans = [0] * 2
    arr = [0.5] * (maxx-2*minn +1)
    for i in range (0, len(ints), 1):
        target = s - ints[i]
        if target >= minn:
            if not arr[target-minn] == 0.5:
                ans[0] = target
                ans[1] = ints[i]
                return ans
        arr[ints[i]-minn] = i
    return None
```

**Problem**

> Given a list of integers and a single sum value, return the first two values (parse from the left please) in order of appearance that adds up to form the sum.

sum_pairs([11, 3, 7, 5],         10)

```
           ^--^      3 + 7 = 10
```

== [3, 7]

> > sum_pairs([4, 3, 2, 3, 4],         6)

```
       ^-----^         4 + 2 = 6, indices: 0, 2 *
          ^-----^      3 + 3 = 6, indices: 1, 3
             ^-----^   2 + 4 = 6, indices: 2, 4
```

* entire pair is earlier, and therefore is the correct answer
== [4, 2]

https://www.codewars.com/kata/54d81488b981293527000c8f/train/python

Comment: Are you sure your code is correct in all cases? The line `minn +- s` is very suspicious because it does nothing.

Comment: @JérômeRichard thanks for noticing that, I've since realised that that line of code had no actual effect in any case so removed it. I've checked it against the 8 tests in code wars and a couple that I made myself and it seems to function correctly every time.

Comment: Hint: consider `s1 = set(ints)` and `s2 = {s - i for i in ints}`. What does the intersection of these two sets represent? How do you make sure you give the right answer with respect to the parsing order? An algorithm built off of this approach should take O(n) time! Let me know if this is too cryptic.

Comment: @Jesse thanks so much for the advice! After a couple more times recompiling I finally got it to be fast enough :)

Comment: Glad that it helped. You can answer your own question with the solution you came up with if you'd like!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that will get you linear execution time:

- create a mapping that associates the index of the first occurrence of each array element.
- then iterate on the array for each index/value:

  - if index is greater than the offset of the current best, break from the loop.
  - if the sum-value is in the array: if its offset is less than the current best, remember the pair.
- at the end of this iteration, either there are no pairs or you have the first pair.